# AngularJS/UI - Focus input in dialogs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there any way to set focus in input controls using AngularJS/Angular-UI ?

I saw that Angular-UI has some Jq-UI=focus directive but I'm unable to get it to work.

I have a few dialogs that I display using Angular-UI $dialog service and would really like the first input on each dialog to get focus once it's shown

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You are missing ui-refresh

Answer (score 19):

I used the standard `autofocus` attribute in my template, and declared a simple directive to make it work for elements that are created after page load (like dialogs in your case).

```
app.directive('autofocus', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element[0].focus();
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Agreed.  Nice simple solution that works well.  I just added it to an ngDialog popup and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Noob here, apologies: What does `restrict: 'A'` do?

Comment: @travis-heeter: it means the directive will be used as an attribute, not an element. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directive-types

Answer (score 10):

Turns out that all you need is this if you use it together with the Angular-ui $dialog service:

```
app.directive('focusMe', function ($timeout) {    
    return {    
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, model) {                
            $timeout(function () {
                element[0].focus();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

html:

```
  <input type="text" focus-me >
```

as stated, this is for Angular-UI $dialog service only.

See it live here: http://strengthtracker.apphb.com   (click login or register to bring up the dialogs)

Comment: How to set focus on the footer buttons .. i am really not able to do so .. i need to close $dialog.messageBox if enter key is pressed

Comment: add a <form> tag around the controls + button in your dialog

Comment: This link appears to be dead.

Comment: please Continue this link, even i want to know how to add focus to footer button. Same issue as what Saurabh asked above

Comment: fyi also works with `$modal` service in Angular which is what `$dialog` was refactored into in later versions of Angular UI

Comment: Why the need for $timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, I've shown demos on how you can call jQuery's native `jQuery.fn.focus()` method on a DOM element, as that's all `ui-jq` really does. The trick is getting it to fire multiple times, and at the right time.

`ui-jq` already executes the method for you inside a `$timeout`, however by default it only fires once, when the DOM element is created. In order to make `ui-jq` fire multiple times, simply add `ui-refresh="someExpression"` and use an expression that you *know* will change every single time the modal opens. It's alright if it refires when the modal is closed too, `.focus()` will do nothing if the DOM element is not visible.

So, for the ui-bootstrap modal, simply put the same expression you're using inside the `modal="someExpression"` and you should be set.

Answer (score -5):

The last version of `AngularJS` offers `ng-focus` : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus

Comment: doesnt work for me, the value passed into the directive watch function is just a string, e.g. 'focusInput' not the evaluated value of focusInput.. something must be wrong?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. No errors thrown, simply nothing happens.

Comment: That's a callback for when a field is focused on.